# Azure ML studio pull directly from sharepoint

Tags: machine-learning

I am toying around with creating a probability of win calculator for proposals that we do. the information on each proposal is housed in our corporate SharePoint (which I am the admin)

Is there a way to pull directly from SharePoint as the data source rather than have to export to xls then upload each time the data updates?